# Is it possible to deploy aspnet vnext to azure from a mac?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core

The kpm pack command needs the runtime for the server - is it possible to install windows runtimes on osx just for the pack and deploy?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that in order to recognise that the deployment is an aspnet vNext project and to handle that as a 'ProjectK Web Application deployment', you have to make it look like it all came from Visual Studio (or at least that was the only way I managed to get it to work right now)...

I did this by taking an example one from somewhere else...
I took a simple single vnext web project .sln file and changed the project name and project GUID.
I took the .kproj Visual Studio project file and did the same.
There isn't much that needs to be changed - only the name of the project and GUID. It's nice that there isn't any file lists in there so I feel that this might end up as a once-only activity...

I did find that there are some project structure rules that seemed to make it break. You seem to have to have the sln file in the top level folder and a folder underneath for the web project. If there is ONLY a web project then this might seem overkill, but I tried collapsing everything up to the top with the sln file correctly pointing, but that didn't work.

The other thing that you need to make sure you have is a reference to "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS" in the project.json dependencies. Without this, the AspNet.Loader.dll and bin folder don't get deployed.

Apart from that, I am now able to use Sublime Text (or whatever I want on osx), test using "k kestrel", checkin through git and it gets deployed automatically to an azure web site! yippee!

Actually this makes much more sense because it is letting the target decide upon the binaries it needs to satisfy the deployments. Next challenge might be to get it to pull 'my' libraries from a custom NuGet source to get my binary libraries in there and avoid uploading ALL of the source to the website!

Oh - and another tip: Quit kestrel with 'Enter' for a clean quit instead of Z which leaves the port listening but non-functional!